# Yolo object detection model - always detects single class and not accurate bounding boxes

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I have created my own dataset and training it using YOLOv3. I have completed training and performing the testing part. My datset consists of 5 classes = ['keyboard', 'mouse','plastic bottle', 'plastic bag','clothes'].

My code to test is:

```
for out in outs:
    for detection in out:
        scores = detection[5:]
        class_id = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[class_id]
        if confidence > 0.2:
            center_x = int(detection[0] * Width)
            center_y = int(detection[1] * Height)
            w = int(detection[2] * Width)
            h = int(detection[3] * Height)
            x = center_x - w / 2
            y = center_y - h / 2
            class_ids.append(class_id)
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
```

When I apply this to an image it is giving me wrong bounding boxes with label plastic bottle.
Also even if I give the image of mouse it is still detecting as plastic bottle.
Can anyone please help me know what error I have made.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide more info about your dataset: how many images per class, their mean size etc). I guess the reason could be wrong labelling, 
insufficient number of examples in the dataset or class imbalance.

Comment: @MaximLyuzin The mistake  was wrong annotation and less number of images for each class. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

The reason:

1. Insufficient Data: The number of images to each class is low. The images of bottle  is the highest whereas the images for other classes is less.
2. Clarity of image: The images in the dataset were from google search. These images have higher resolution and hence the test data image lacked resolution of the image.
3. Wrong annotations: Some of the images are not correctly classified.